# UITableView no. of rows not dynamic after table reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a tableView in a ViewController. In the `viewDidLoad` I have this piece of code:

```
        Alamofire.request(
        URL(string: "https://AAA/BBB")!,
        method: .get,
        parameters: ["uid": Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]).responseJSON { response in // method defaults to `.get`
            print(response)
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 200:
                        if let result = response.result.value {
                        self.JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                        self.goalsArray = Array(self.JSON.allKeys)
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                default:
                    print("error with response status: \(status): ")
                }
            }

    }
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

Then to load the table I have this function:

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    print("called")
    return goalsArray.count
}
```

By my understanding, the table should load all the data elements present in `goalsArray` and display them. But that doesn't happen

[image: One element present in goalsArray]

[image: 4 elements present in goalsArray]

As you can see from the screenshot, irrespective of the number of elements in the array, three rows are show(in the second screenshot there were 4 elements in the array). What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: You should reload the table view on the main thread. What is `self.self`? And don't use `NSArray/NSDictionary` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system.

Comment: reloading on the main thread did not work. ` DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }`. self.self was a mistake, edited it.

Comment: This line is wrong: self.goalsArray = self.allkeys.filter { !itemToRemove.contains($0 as! String) } as NSArray. -- it is unclear what you're trying to achieve, but your filter func isn't filtering anything inside goalsArray, but it is uselessly verifying if $0 element from goalsArray is not contained in itemToRemove and just doesn't do anything else.